# Google Firebase - Firestore - plain javascript - db.collection.update() initially duplicates the list item before browser refresh, why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and it's use in some basic web technologies. I'm following the fantastic NetNinja series for creating a basic Google Firebase - Firestore app. The majority of the code below is taken from the class, however I am trying to add a function to update a boolean field following a click on the li item (see line 26 - app.js). The update is toggling the value of the boolean.

I am experiencing an issue where the li item is being duplicated and is showing up twice in the list, when I refresh the browser the duplicated li item disappears. The field value is updating in firestore correctly, and I can see the changes in firestore - I'm  just not sure about my implementation of the db.collection().doc().update() function.

Note - currently I'm only opening the index.html file locally, in Chrome (but I don't think that is causing this issue). I've tried doing the update directly in the console, but I seem to get the same behaviour - leading me to think it's my implementation of the update function.

Any help would be very gladly appreciated, along with improvements and explanations. Many thanks in advance!

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Bob Things</h1>

        <div class="content">
            <form id="add-item-form">
                <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Bob item">
                <input type="text" name="replenish" placeholder="true">
                <button>Add Item</button>
            </form>
            <ul id="item-list"></ul>
        </div>

        <script>
        // Initialise Firebase
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDccrM8EErMCUUc4XUdkEytPDwUuJryxrA",
            authDomain: "firestore-test-5b316.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "firestore-test-5b316",
            storageBucket: "firestore-test-5b316.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "588262547847",
            appId: "1:588262547847:web:3bf82908cce90ec8e3f322"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots:true ,merge:true});
        </script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const itemList = document.querySelector('#item-list');
const form = document.querySelector('#add-item-form');
const collectionVal = "bob_things"

// Create element and render info
function renderItems(doc){
    
    // Set variables and setup li elements
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let item = document.createElement('span');
    let replenish = document.createElement('span');
    let cross = document.createElement('div');   

    li.setAttribute('data-id',doc.id);
    item.textContent = doc.data().item;
    replenish.textContent = doc.data().replenish;
    cross.textContent = 'x';

    // Add to main li
    li.appendChild(item);
    li.appendChild(replenish);
    li.appendChild(cross);
    itemList.appendChild(li);

    // Onclick should change
    li.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        console.log('here');
        let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        let replenishNewVal = !doc.data().replenish;
        db.collection(collectionVal).doc(id).update({
            replenish: replenishNewVal
        })
        .then(() =>{
            console.log('Updated '+doc.data().item);
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            console.error('Error updating',error);
        })
    })

    // Deleting a list item
    cross.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        e.stopPropagation();
        let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        db.collection(collectionVal).doc(id).delete();
    })
}

// Saving Data
form.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection(collectionVal).add({
        item: form.item.value,
        replenish: form.replenish.value
    })
    form.item.value = '';
    form.replenish.value = '';
})

// Realtime listener
db.collection(collectionVal).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    console.log('ran the listener');
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
        if (change.type == 'added' || change.type == 'modified'){
            renderItems(change.doc);
        } else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let li = itemList.querySelector('[data-id='+change.doc.id+']');
            itemList.removeChild(li);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: When you say you're "opening the index.html file locally," do you mean you're using a local webserver? Or do you mean you're just opening the file over the `file://` protocol? They're very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
db.collection(collectionVal).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    console.log('ran the listener');
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
        if (change.type == 'added' || change.type == 'modified'){ //  For new or updated item
            renderItems(change.doc); //  add a new LI item to the HTML
        } else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let li = itemList.querySelector('[data-id='+change.doc.id+']');
            itemList.removeChild(li);
        }
    })
})
```

So for every new or updated item, you're adding a new LI to the HTML. But when a document is updated in the database, you should actually *update* the corresponding LI in the HTML instead of creating a new one.

The simplest fix based on your existing code is to remove the LI, and then re-add it:

```
if (change.type == 'removed' || change.type == 'modified'){
    let li = itemList.querySelector('[data-id='+change.doc.id+']');
    itemList.removeChild(li);
}
if (change.type == 'added' || change.type == 'modified'){
    renderItems(change.doc);
}
```

So now `modified` is handled twice: once to remove the existing LI, and once to add a new one.

---

While the above works, a better solution would be to look up the existing LI in the HTML, and then update it with the data from the modified document. I recommend giving this a try yourself, as it'll give you a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thanks very much Frank - that has helped! Many thanks for the clearly explained answer.